# openLDAP ldap_modify: Server is unwilling to perform (53) when trying to delete custom schema

Tags: ldap, openldap, schema, ldif

I have created this custom and very basic schema:

```
objectclass ( 2.25.2.2.1
    NAME 'myObjectClass'
    DESC 'myObjectClass objectclass'
    STRUCTURAL
    MUST ( cn )
    )
```

I have added it without problem with this myObjectClass.ldif file:

```
dn: cn=myObjectClass,cn=schema,cn=config
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: myObjectClass
olcObjectClasses: {0}( 2.25.2.2.1 NAME 'myObjectClass' DESC 'myObjectClass objectclass' STRUCTURAL MUST cn )
```

Using ldapmodify:

```
sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f myObjectClass.ldif
```

Now I'm trying to delete it with delete.ldif:

```
dn: cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: objectClass
objectClass: 2.25.2.2.1
```

Using ldapmodify always get ldap_modify: Server is unwilling to perform (53):

```
sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f delete.ldif
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "cn=schema,cn=config"
ldap_modify: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
```

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 Server with OpenLDAP 2.4.31

I have searched this [in the official docs](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/guide.html#Better%20%7B%7BB:cn=schema%7D%7D%20functionality):

> A.2.2. Better cn=schema functionality
>
> In 2.3 you were only able to add new schema elements, not delete or
>   modify existing elements. In 2.4 you can modify schema at will.
>   (Except for the hardcoded system schema, of course.)

Can someone share any clue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to modify schema configuration in 2.4 version of the Openldap server is:

- Remove all entries who use this schema

Then

> stopping slapd using slapcat to export the dynamic config to LDIF
>   Modifying the LDIF export to remove the schema in question Remove (or
>   rename) your old dynamic config directory slapadd the updated LDIF
>   start slapd

According [this talk](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201204/msg00245.html) on the official site.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but, maybe my answer will help anyone else (including myself in the future)

My OpenLDAP version : slapd  (Ubuntu) (Apr 10 2019 12:53:11)

I know that we should never manually edit configuration files, but I already use ldapmodify, ldapdelete none works. This is my last resort that actually works.

```
cd /etc/ldap
mv slapd.d /var/backups/slapd.d.bak
mkdir slapd.d
slapcat -n0 -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d.old/ > /tmp/config-in-portable-format.ldif
```

Edit the file /tmp/config-in-portable-format.ldif here...

```
slapadd -n0 -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d -l /tmp/config-in-portable-format.ldif
chown -R openldap:openldap slapd.d/
chmod -R 755 slapd.d/
/etc/init.d/slapd restart
```

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered this error while trying to add a schema using

`sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f chdomain.ldif`

and it was telling me:

"**ldap_modify: Server is unwilling to perform (53) additional info: no global superior knowledge**"

I figured out my ldif file was not well formatted (notice the space i had before the distinguished name).
[screenshot of my ldif file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5bxU.png)